# This is not a duplicate - Why does Jesus say he came not to abolish the law while Paul in Ephesians 2:14-15 say that Christ abolished the law?

Tags: discussion

Question are closed because it says it is a duplicate.  Link 1 & 2 have been closed as duplicates.

However link 1 & 2 ask about contradiction between Matthew 5:17-20 & Ephesians 2:14-15.

Link 3 only ask about 'Ephesians 2:15 exactly what part of the Law has been abolished?'

You can not explain the contradiction at Matt and Eph on link 3 - otherwise you are not answering the questions.

Link 1 or 2 need to re-open

1 - [Why does Jesus say he came not to abolish the law while Paul in Ephesians 2:14-15 say that Christ abolished the law?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/76141/33268)

2 - [Did Ephesians 2:15 intend to contradict Mathew 5:17?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/25950/33268)

3 - [In Ephesians 2:15 exactly what part of the Law has been abolished?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/19448/33268)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that question 2 is not a duplicate of 3, and have reopened it. Thank you for pointing out this inaccurate duplicate closure.

But I think question 1 is a duplicate of 2, so have not reopened it.

Comment: Thank you for this

Comment: I have had another look at this and believe that Q1 should be opened as well as it actually asking something different to Q2. Q2 asks if its a deliberate contradiction, (accepting it as a contradiction) arguably what would be the reason for the deliberate contradiction.  Yet Q1 is asking something completely different - why Jesus says one thing and Paul says another.  Arguably this may not be a contradiction.  It would also make sense to open something recent then something so old.  They both need to be answered in 2 different ways.

Comment: Can you confirm your position on my comment above or do I need to open a new chat

Comment: @anothertheory My position is what I wrote in the answer. I don't think I need to say anything more. If you think a question should be reopened you are free to vote to reopen it.